# Angi's camp follower archery

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I am wondering if I bring followers to angi's camp will they use the archery range or just hang out

Answer (score 1):

As it is not a real player home, but rather a location the followers will not interact with the archery range and just hang out as they do in any other location/vista.

Comment: If I used a mod to change an npcs home hold that work or no

Comment: I need a link to the mod in order to give you a full answer. But in theory, that could work.

Comment: It's the relocate npcs your new home for ps4 on bethesda.net